# Существуют ли правила вёрстки email-писем, распространяемые почтовыми сервисами?

Tags: вёрстка-email

Существуют ли правила вёрстки email-писем, распространяемые почтовыми сервисами? В том числе яндекс.почта и тому подобные сервисы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не существуют. Используйте `mjml` для верстки писем, чтобы это было везде корректно.